# How to override the DbContext in ServiceCollection during runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am working on a multi-tenant system, where in most scenarios the `TenantIdentifier` will be passed to the API in the HTTP Header.
In these scenarios I can retrieve the `TenantIdentifier` in the Middleware and then set the `DbContext` to point to the Tenant DB.

Like so, where `ITenantContext` is just a class to retrieve the Tenant information from the HTTP Header:

```
services.AddDbContext<TenantDbContext>((s, o) =>
{
    var connectionStringBuilder = s.GetService<IConnectionStringBuilder>();

    var tenant = s.GetService<ITenantContext>()?.Tenant;
    var connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.TenantConnectionString(tenant?.Name) 
                ?? DbConstants.DEV_DEFAULT_TENANT_CONNECTION_STRING;

    o.UseSqlServer(connectionString, builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(TenantDbContext).Assembly.FullName));
});
```

Now, in some scenarios we don't know the Tenant, and it is not present in the HTTP Header.
an example maybe User Login, Password reset etc.

I need to somehow Remove the `TenantDbContext` and create it in the code down the layers.
My question is, how do I Remove and ReAdd the `TenantDbContext`  from the `ServiceCollection` or `ServiceProvider`.

In the integration tests, we have access to `WebApplicationFactory`, and we can do something like this to create the TenantDbContext for the integration test DB.

But what is the alternative for Non-Integration test code?

```
builder.ConfigureServices((builder, services) =>
{
    services
    .Remove<DbContextOptions<TenantDbContext>>()
    .AddDbContext<TenantDbContext>((sp, options) =>
            options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultTenantDbConnection"),
                builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(TenantDbContext).Assembly.FullName)));
});
```

I tried putting in something to Build a Tenant specific `ServiceProvider`, but that means every single service configuration will have to be included in this and the actual Web API `ServiceCollection`. Which will cause alot of confusion in the future.

```
public class TenantServiceProviderBuilder : ITenantServiceProviderBuilder
{
    private readonly IConnectionStringBuilder _connectionStringBuilder;

    public TenantServiceProviderBuilder(IConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder)
    {
        _connectionStringBuilder = connectionStringBuilder;
    }

    public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }

    public IServiceProvider Build(string tenantIdentifier)
    {
        string connectionString = _connectionStringBuilder.TenantConnectionString(tenantIdentifier);


        // TODO: Really should look for a better way to do this - this will lead to alot of issues down the line.
        // we somehow should copy over the existing ServiceCollection into this new one created`var services = new ServiceCollection();`
        // otherwise we will have to manually add all the services here again.
        // this is not the correct way to do this.
        // services should be registered in a single place then handled accordingly!

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddLogging();

        services.AddDbContext<TenantDbContext>((s, o) =>
        {
            o.UseSqlServer(connectionString, builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(TenantDbContext).Assembly.FullName));
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services
            .AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TenantDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddTransient<IIdentityService, IdentityService>();
        services.AddTransient<IAuthService, AuthService>();

        ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        return ServiceProvider;
    }
}
```

I know this goes against DI practices, so open to suggestions on an alternative way to implement this.

Comment: Assume the ServiceProvider is shared; don't modify it. Instead reconsider why you think you need to remove the `TenantDbContext`. Instead, try not needing it during those requests.

Comment: Refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69004937/how-to-replace-registrations-at-runtime-after-the-servicecollection-was-built), I don't think you can remove and readd service to ServiceCollection at runtime.